# How to build gcc without make?

Tags: compiling, make, gcc

I'm trying to build tools from source codes. I start with make and get the following error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

So it means that I need to install gcc. But as you may guess it requires make tool. gcc-9.3.0 installation instructions says:

> "GNU make version 3.80 (or later)
>   You must have GNU make installed to build GCC."

It seems to me a chicken-egg problem. Am I missing something?

P.S: I know it's easy to install one of them from distro's packages source. But I want to build them from source code.

Comment: How did you build the shell that you're using to run these commands? :)  Bootstrapping your system usually depends on having a small set of pre-compiled binaries to start off with.  You'll need a compiler to build the compiler (independent of needing one to build `make`).

Comment: You should really write an assembler in binary, then use the assembler to make a C compiler, then ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I want to build them from source code.

You really do need a C compiler to prime the pump. Even in the old days of getting GNU going on systems such as SunOS, you’d start by building the tools using the native C compiler (or later, by using GCC binaries built by someone else). Make is only one of the tools you need to build GCC; once you’ve got past the Make hurdle, you’ll find you need GCC to build GCC...

I recommend [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) if you want to explore building a system from source, it will explain all the various steps in detail.